# Incompatible types Required: File, Found:void

Tags: java, pojo

I'm trying to programatically set the ID3 tags of some mp3s. After having gave up the jaudiotagger I found the MyID3 library http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/

I'm by no means an experienced Java programmer, but I have some knowledge of OOP.
I managed to get as far as writing a class, everything works well, except for a strange error, that I can't understand.
My class is:

```
    import org.cmc.music.myid3.*;
import org.cmc.music.metadata.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;



/**
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
class lrsetid3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String files;
        File inputfolder = new File("c:\\ID3\\input");
        File[] listOfFiles = inputfolder.listFiles(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
                {
//                      files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            }
            try {
                MusicMetadataSet src_set = new MyID3().read(listOfFiles[i]);


                IMusicMetadata metadata = src_set.getSimplified();
                String artist = metadata.getArtist(); 
                    metadata.setArtist("Bob Marley");
                    System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                        File src = new File ("c:\\ID3\\input" + listOfFiles[i].getName());                      
                        System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].isFile());
                        System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].exists());

                    File dst = new MyID3().write(src, dst, src_set, metadata);              
//                  System.out.println("Artist" + artist); // Display the string.


            }
            catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        }



    }
```

And the error that I get is on the line:
                    File dst = new MyID3().write(src, dst, src_set, metadata);

```
    lrsetid3.java:37: error: incompatible types
                                        File dst = new MyID3().write(src, dst, src_set, metadata);
                                                                    ^
  required: File
  found:    void
1 error
```

The weird part is that the printouts say that the first parameter of the write function is a File... I do not get why the compiler does not want to accept src as a File variable.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: there's a missing `}` for closing the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that will return a new MyID3 object.

```
File dst = new MyID3();
```

This however, will return what the write() method returns. In this case void. (I presume)

```
File dst = new MyID3().write(src, dst, src_set, metadata);
```

To fix it, do this:

```
File dst = new MyID3();
dst.write(src, dst, src_set, metadata);
```

And of course, the same rule applies to this line:

```
MusicMetadataSet src_set = new MyID3().read(listOfFiles[i]);
```

Comment: Merci René I've tried this before posting, but there is no MyID3 constructor, I get the error : C:\ID3>javac -cp .;jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar;myid3.jar lrsetid3.java
lrsetid3.java:38: error: incompatible types
                                                File dst = new MyID3();
                                                           ^
  required: File
  found:    MyID3
1 error

Comment: Quite wired the stackoverflow, I want to post the MyID3.java file, but I can't, I'm new to it as well, and I can't find the code tag either, is it a <code> </code> ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this line MusicMetadataSet src_set = new MyID3().read(listOfFiles[i]); works well

Comment: The source file of the MyID3 library can be found here http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/myid3-src.zip

Comment: @MMT I checked out the source files you posted. The `MyID3` class doesn't extends the `File` class. Most of its methods does require a `File` object though. So create a new `File` object and pass it to the `MyID3` object method.

Comment: File src = new File ("c:\\ID3\\input\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName());

Comment: Merci René                     I realised that there was an error(I forgot to add a trailing slash after the input folder, I've corrected it and changed the problematic lines to      MyID3 test = new MyID3();      

       test.write(src, src, src_set, metadata);        
 Now there are no more compile errors but the Artist tag is not saved to Bob Marley